# Objective-C: create button without fill

Tags: ios, objective-c, fill

How to create rounded button programmatically without fill like on image?

[image](https://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fionicframework.com%2Fimg%2Fdocs%2Foutline-button-ex.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fionicframework.com%2Fdocs%2Fv2%2Fcomponents%2F&docid=dUcSUVX1ujCJ0M&tbnid=vrZN24IE0LOg2M%3A&w=282&h=88&safe=strict&client=safari&bih=739&biw=1280&ved=0ahUKEwji-srWwtLOAhVGiSwKHVmeA6w4ZBAzCC0oKzAr&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I wan to say the above answer did not give you the exact solution even he gave the key point for rounded corner.

If you want to get rounded corner without fill like above that image,mostly we should go with CALayer.

You have to import **Quartzcore framework** first.In above answer he did not mention that.

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then creating button with rounded corners

```
UIButton *btnRoundedCorner = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       OR
UIButton *btnRoundedCorner= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
btnRoundedCorner.frame = CGRectMake(20, 60, 150, 100);
[btnRoundedCorner setTitle:@"Outline Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnRoundedCorner setTitleColor:[UIColor  redColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"]; //If you want to set the image set here
//If you want to add or set Background image for button
[btnRoundedCorner setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//If you want to add or set image for button
[btnRoundedCorner setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnRoundedCorner addTarget:self action:@selector(actionForRoundedCorner:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnRoundedCorner];


//Rounded Corner
btnRoundedCorner.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
btnRoundedCorner.layer.borderWidth = 1;
btnRoundedCorner.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
btnRoundedCorner.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the `layer` properties to add on outline to any `UIView` (`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`)

**Objective-C**

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
[button setTitle:@"Outline Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Swift**

```
let button = UIButton(type: .System)
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
button.setTitle("Outline Button", forState: .Normal)
```